The minimum size of substrings for the presence of at least one character
i have a question that want the minimum length of k that in each consecutive substring of a string with length k, There must be at least one common character.
for example if s="abcaca"
for k = 1 --> substrings are [a], [b], [c] and etc that we can not find a common char in all.
for k = 2 --> [ab], [bc], [ca] ... that again there is no a common char in all
but for k = 3 we have [abc], [bca], [cac] [aca] that a and c are in all substrings so answer is k.
or for s="abc" we have k=2 same as above description. my code work correct but its not optimal for large length of s. can anyone solve this with dynamic sliding  window or other optimal ways ?
n = input()

queue = list(n)

k = 1
s1 = 0
s2 = 1
last_intersection = None
sub_1 = set(queue[0:1])

while (s2 + k) < len(queue) + 1:
    sub_2 = set(queue[s2: s2 + k])
    if len(sub_2.intersection(sub_1)) > 0:
        sub_1 = sub_2.intersection(sub_1)
        s2 += 1
    else:
        s1 = 0
        s2 = 1
        k += 1
        sub_1 = set(queue[s1: s1 + k])

print(k)


k could be any number and we should find the min value of k that we have a common character in consecutive substrings with  k length. it doesnt matter string length be multiple of k or not.

we should check k from 1 until we reach to the end of the string or when we have a substring with length k that the last character of that is the last character of the string:
for example in s="abc" we can have 3 consecutive substring with k=1 : 'a' , 'b', 'c' and we can have 2 substring with k=2 : 'ab', 'bc' , we can have k=3 too but the smallest k that satisfies the condition of the problem is k=2 because we can find a char ('b') in all consecutive substrings with length 2 that we can.

What limitations? String length, alphabet size?

@MBo just string size is between 1 and 100,000

This can be solved in linear time in the length of the string by finding the minimum of all maximum distances between nearest occurrences of the same character (like also described by user58697).
Here is the implementation:
def solve(s: str) -> int:
    prev_idx, max_dist = {}, {}
    for i, c in enumerate(s):
        max_dist[c], prev_idx[c] = max(max_dist.get(c, 0), i - prev_idx.get(c, -1)), i
    return min(max(d, len(s) - prev_idx[c]) for c, d in max_dist.items())

print(solve("abcaca")) # 3
print(solve("abc"))    # 2
print(solve("bbaaac")) # 3
print(solve("aaab"))   # 2


Thanks, thats work in linear time and solve my problem

@AmirHossein Happy to help.

For all substrings to contain a, the length of a substring must be the maximal distance between individual as. Ditto for b, c, etc.
So, for each character in the alphabet find a maximal distance between its occurrences, and pick the minimal of those. Computing maximal distances can be done in a single pass over a string, and selecting the minimum in a single pass over the alphabet.

Consider the s = "bbaaac" , the correct k is 3, jow your answer can solve this ?

Don't forget the lead-in and lead-out. For a to appear in the very first substring, it must have a length of 3: bba. For b to appear in the very last substring, it must have length of 5: baaac.

i know but what about b?? The max distance  for b is 1 and the lead is 1 too, so the minimal between 1, 3 and 5 is 1 but correct answer is 3, or in s=""aaab" ,  for a distance is 1 and for b is 4 , but the correct answer is 2

Don't forget lead-out. For b in the first string it is 4, and for a in the second it is 2.

Here is the logic:
s = "abcaca"

k = 1
n = len(s) # length of string s
while k < n:
    a = set(s[:k])
    for i in range(n - k + 1):
        a &= set(s[i:i+k]) # intersection
        if not a: break  #if intersection is empty, no need to continue.
    if a: break #if after traversing the string, intersection is not empty, break
    k += 1
print(k)
3 



the answer is correct but still i give time limit exceeded for large strings.

@AmirHossein what is the length of your string?

the length is between 1 and 100000

We can use binary search for efficiency:
def solve(s):
    def find(k):
        A = set(s[:k])
        for i in range(1, n - k + 1):
            A &= set(s[i:i + k])
            if len(A) == 0:
                return False
        return True
    n = len(s)
    lo, hi = 1, len(s)
    while lo <= hi:
        mid = (lo + hi) // 2
        if find(mid):
            hi = mid - 1
        else:
            lo = mid + 1
    return lo


print(solve("abcaca"))  # [abc], [bca], [cac] [aca]
print(solve("abc"))
print(solve("abcacaabcdabcdeabcdeabcde"))


Prints
3
2
5



Dont think this function is binary searchable.

the answer is correct but still i give time limit exceeded for large strings. is any other  way to decrease time complexity ?
